# javascript api call, send and handle data in specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this API call where i make sure the data return in the same order i send it. However, i realized thats not really what i want, i want to make sure the data is send and taken care of one at a time.

*data[n] has returned before data[n+1] is send.*

**the reason for this is:**

If i do it as seen below, the server still gets it in a random order, and therefor saves the data in my DB in a random order. (or well not random, heavier data gets processed slower)

```
var promiseArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var dataPromise = $http.post('/api/bla/blabla', $httpParamSerializer(data[i]))
    .then (function (response) {
         //return data for chaining
         return response.data;
    });
promiseArray.push(dataPromise);
}

$q.all(promiseArray).then(function (dataArray) {
 //succes 
}).catch (function (errorResponse) {
 //error
});
```

how can i make sure the data is send and processed and returned, one at a time in a smooth way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var i = -1;
processNextdata();

function processNextdata() {
    i++;

    if(angular.isUndefined(data[i]))
        return;

    $http.post('/api/bla/blabla', $httpParamSerializer(data[i]))
        .then(processNextdata)
}
```

Update:

Callback after every result:

```
var i = -1;
processNextdata();

function processNextdata() {
    i++;

    if(angular.isUndefined(data[i]))
        return;

    $http.post('/api/bla/blabla', $httpParamSerializer(data[i]))
        .then(function(result) {
            // do something with a single result

            return processNextdata();
        }, errorCallback);
}
```

Callback after everything is done:

```
var i = -1, resultData = [];
processNextdata()
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }, errorCallback);

function processNextdata() {
    i++;

    if(angular.isUndefined(data[i]))
        return resultData;

    $http.post('/api/bla/blabla', $httpParamSerializer(data[i]))
        .then(function(result) {
            resultData.push(result.data);
            return processNextdata();
        }, $q.reject);
}
```

Comment: how would you add success and error callback to this ?

Comment: do you want a success callback after everything is finished or after every request ?

Comment: when they are all finished.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Promise.all([...])` method, the documentation shows the following:

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when *all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved*, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

What this tells us is that there is no expected order of synchronized operations, but in fact the promises run parallel to one another and can complete in any order.

In your case, there **is** an expected order that you want your promises to run in, so using `Promise.all([...])` won't satisfy your requirements.

What you can do instead is execute individual promises, then if you have some that can run in parallel use the `Promise.all([...])` method.

I would create a method that takes a request as an argument, then returns the generated promise:

```
function request (req) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request({
        url: url
        , port: <port>
        , body: req
        , json: <true/false>
        , method: '<POST/GET>'
        , headers: {

        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(body);
        }
    });
});
```

You can then call this function and store the result:

```
var response = request(myRequest);
```

Alternatively, you could create an array of your requests and then call the function:

```
var requests  = [request1, request2, ..., requestN];
var responses = [];
for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
   responses.push(request(requests[i]));
}
```